# Spring MVC application with 404 error

Tags: java, spring-mvc

My Spring release is 5.x and tomcat version is 8.5, so according to introduction, they will support the web application running without web.xml, but I got 404 error, see my project structure below:

[image]

I use this url to access my application, but got 404 error:
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/

see my code below:

**RootConfig.java:**

```
package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"spitter"},
               excludeFilters= {@Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=EnableWebMvc.class)}
              )
public class RootConfig {

}
```

**WebConfig.java:**

```
package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("spittr.web")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    public ViewResolver viewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) 
    {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

**SpittrWebAppInitializer.java:**

```
package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpittrWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {RootConfig.class}; 
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}
```

**HomeController.java:**

```
package spittr.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home()
    {
        System.out.println("test");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**home.jsp:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>this is the Home Jsp page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, Spring MVC!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

from the Eclipse console, I can see output "test" that means spring context find out the controller, but seems it cannot find the jsp page, I don't know the reason, can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: try adding @Bean annotation on top of public ViewResolver viewResolver() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding @Bean annotation on top of `WebConfig#viewResolver()` method. So, the Spring Container manage your method as bean and your custom configuration will probably work.

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver(){}
```

> Indicates that a method produces a bean to be managed by the Spring
>   container.